# Force close background service/application in every case using c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows service written in c# .net4.6.
Whenever this service receives any message, it opens the excel application, write some data from the message it received, run some calculations (which are predefined), save the output into another file and close the excel application.
All these activities are working fine exception for closing the excel application which runs as a background service.

I have opened a excel applicaton like this :

```
Object excelObject = Interaction.CreateObject("Excel.Application", null);
```

I'm trying to close the application by this line :

```
 int processID = excelObject.CurrentProcessID;
 Process myProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processID); // gets stuck here
 myProcess.Kill();
```

This works 99% of the times, but once in a while it gets stuck and I'm unable to figure out why. I have to manually open task manager and end the task for excel running in background service.

Can there be any reason why this happens. And is there any way I want to force close it anyways.
Any help in this regard is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Automating the office apps when not running interactively has *never* been supported by Microsoft - [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) (or variants thereof) has existed for over 2 decades.